# Node.js installation fails with WARNING 1909 on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows

Node.js is failing to install on Windows 10 with the following warning messages. As a user, I made sure to have `Full access` to the folder *C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs*. I've also created an install log by running `msiexec /i node-v18.16.0-x64.msi /l*v InstallLog.txt` in an admin prompt, which can be accessed in the form of GitHub gist [here](https://gist.github.com/wasimaftab/58669f3ffcf0a59fbd9b0e963efa6fca#file-installlog-txt).

[image]

Once I click `OK` on the above pop-up box, I get some more warnings, I'm pasting them below

[image]

[image]
[image]

Then the installer rolls back (see image below)

[image]

and fails with the final warning as shown below

[image]

I will appreciate any suggestions/solutions to solve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by deleting `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Node.js` folder that was created by the older installer.

During the latest installation, it got created anyway.